# How to detect a very old version of Edge

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, compatibility, browserstack

I am looking for a solution on the comment to detect the browser Edge44 in Linux.
I have Ubuntu and i made a test in browserstack, but it does not have Edge44.

Comment: Do you want to detect Edge Legacy in some languages like javascript or css? If so, please tell us which language you want to use so that we can help.

Comment: Besides, Edge 44 is EdgeHTML 18: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyoNo.png , you can test it in browserstack by selecting Microsoft Edge 18: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFerR.png.

Answer (score 0):

Edge 44 is the same as Edge 18. The difference lies in the naming convention. Edge 44 refers to the 'Edge version' whereas Edge 18 is the 'EdgeHTML' version. [More on this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Release_strategy).

I believe they do offer Edge 18? Googling around gave me this - https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms/live